Which Chainlink's price feeds still have `minAnswer` and `maxAnswer` checks?
Chainlink's website says minAnswer and maxAnswer are deprecated on most Price Feeds, so the questions is, is it possible to know the specific Price Feeds where these are not deprecated yet? Unfortunately, can't see it on your website.
Tried exploring the Chainlink's website and googling, exploring price feeds themselves, but didn't find anything specific.

You can check out each feed listed here:
https://data.chain.link/feeds
And select which feed you'd like check then click the contract address that links you to etherscan.
That contract address is actually the proxy contract. You can click the read contract tab on etherscan to check out all the functions.
The proxy contract does not expose the minAnswer and maxAnswer functions so you need to check the aggregator function and then click on that contract address which is the aggregator address.
From there go to read contract again and there you will see there are the minAnswer and maxAnswer.
If the minAnswer has a value of 1 and the maxAnswer has a value of 95780971304118053647396689196894323976171195136475135 then that theoretically means there is no min or max for that feeds since 1 is the least value that aggregator can generate and 95780971304118053647396689196894323976171195136475135 is the max answer.
If the values are those are set other than those mentioned above then that means there are actually min and max for that feed - which you will need to take into consideration the decimal value from that point.
Hope that helps :)
